# Override my own resource bundle entry

Tags: jsf-2, resourcebundle, message-bundle

In JSF, it's easy to override Messages from the default resource bundle:

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = {0}: Please enter value
```

I would like to use the same mechanism for my own library containing JSF resource bundles, composite components and utility classes. In this library I define a bundle:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>amed</base-name>
    <var>am</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

And in my webapp which uses this library:

a) default case

```
#{am['key']} fetches the value from the library (OK)
```

b) special case where I try to override the property from the library in another resource bundle:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>webappbundle</base-name>
    <var>wb</var>
</resource-bundle>


#{am['key']} should fetch the overritten property from webappbundle (DOES NOT WORK)
```

I know, it's not the right way to solve the problem but perhaps you understand my question and can give me an alternative solution.

BTW: I don't want to override a complete bundle, only some keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it's not possible to override only some keys of a ResourceBundle. But you can override complete bundles.